# Flutter application is running in emulator but Flutter Widget Inspector is not displaying

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, inspector, flutter-devtools

I am running my flutter app successfully on my emulator.  However, I need the use of the Widget Inspector for testing purposes.

To run my app I use the following:

`flutter run --flavor dev -t lib/main_prod.dart`

However, when I use the palette to bring up the "Open DevTools" I end up getting what is shown in the image

[image: noInspector]

I've run flutter clean before running my app and it still didn't work.

Please help!

Comment: what are you using as IDE/editor?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out.

I was looking for the typical pop-up tool bar and overlooked this:
[image: keyCommands]

Simply pressing "h" for "List all available interactive commands." brought up a more comprehensive list with the option for an inspector:

[image: moreKeyCommands]

Pressing "v" to open the flutter tools here works.

Answer (score 0):

When you run it by your command in a terminal, you will see the URL which is generated during the process.

[Enter this URL to connect in DevTools on your browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czcxa.png)

If your project requires to use of an old version of 3.3.9, you could do it. If not, you could upgrade to version 3.7.4